# How I can implement a ExpandableListView in java (for Android) that make click display items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm trying to implement a ExpandableListView in java that when click deployment space elements inside, not the typical wish list allows choosing an option. What I try to do is basically something like this

[image]

One can see that the spinner "wraps" to have items and does not have a list, Would I could help a little?

Comment: it's not a spinner, it's `ExpandableListView` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: @nikis Thanks for the clarification, how can I implemente in java??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExpandableListView` .. check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create one on your own. Just create a `Button` and assign a `Layout` below. When the `Button` gets clicked set the `View` of you `Layout` to `Visible` and otherwise to `Invisible`. Additionaly you can set up and down arrows to the right of your `Button`.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.expand, 0);

                } else {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.collapse, 0);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: nteresting solution, but my problem is to create the "LinearLayout" with java code and not using XML